# How to get Paginator->numbers() to Display 1

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, navigation, numbers, paginator

I'm not sure if this is as easy as I think, but I want to get the paginator to display 1 when there is only a single page for my table.

I was thinking it was possible to do something like this:

```
<p> <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>;
    <?php if(1 >= $this->Paginator->numbers())
                echo 1;
            else
                echo $this->Paginator->numbers();   ?>
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>; </p>
```

But then I realized that paginator->numbers() returns links in the form of 1|2|3 and so on.

Currently the paginator will display:

```
<<Previous Next>>
```

when there is only one page in the table but for 2 or more pages it shows

```
<<Previous 1|2 Next>>
```

I would like to have it to show a number at all times, including 1 for a single page table.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: I've done what you showed above to overcome that. Haven't looked into it, though, so there may be another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create an element called `pagination.ctp` and put the following inside:

```
<p>
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
    $numbers = $this->Paginator->numbers();
    if (empty($numbers)) {
        $numbers = 1; // or any markup you need
    }
    echo $numbers;
    echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
</p>
```

Then whenever you need to:

```
<?php echo $this->element('pagination'); ?>
```